# Apache CXF logging SOAP XML in /tmp folder

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf, camel-cxf

Apache CXF (version 3.2.4) is logging all my soap xml messages in /tmp folder.

I am using LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor as cxf interceptors in the cxfEndpoint provided in the Apache CAMEL (version 2.22.0) framework.

I see in the CachedOutputStream code of CXF Framework that its logging the soap messages to temp folder.

Is there a property or configuration in CXF which deletes the files automatically after the response is rendered.

Comment: I tried following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287431/optimizing-cxf-webservice
to change the threshold value, still no luck.

Comment: How can I set the below values using the Bus created by CamelTransportFactory 

<cxf:properties>
 <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="${schema.validation.enabled}" /> 
<entry key="bus.io.CachedOutputStream.Threshold" value="512000"/> 
<entry key="bus.io.CachedOutputStream.MaxSize" value="1000000000"/> <entry key="bus.io.CachedOutputStream.OutputDirectory" value="/opt/cxf/logs/"/> 
</cxf:properties>


At the moment, these properties are not getting picked. Any help would be appreciated